# Quadratic function error using portfolio.optimum

Tags: r, portfolio

I am creating a stock portfolio and I want to run an efficiency frontier. I am running into an error with my portfolio optimum code. I am also noticing that all the stocks have the same monthly return. I am working through this error at the time. Any help with either of my problems would be greatly apprecieated

```
tickers <- c('DPZ','SPY','AMD','AAPL','TSLA','MSFT','V', 'WMT', 'SQ','EA','ATVI','AMZN','ROKU', 
'PYPL','KO','AXP','CCL','DFS')
 Portfolio1 <- getSymbols.yahoo(tickers[1], from="2016-01-01", to= "2018-12-31", auto.assign=FALSE)


 Portfolio2 <- Portfolio1[,6]
 my_portfolio <- monthlyReturn(Portfolio2)

 for(i in 2:length(tickers)){
   ticker1 <- c('DPZ','SPY','AMD','AAPL','TSLA','MSFT','V', 'WMT', 'SQ','EA','ATVI','AMZN','ROKU', 
  'PYPL','KO','AXP','CCL','DFS')
   getSymbols.yahoo(tickers[i], from="2016-01-01", to= "2018-12-31", auto.assign=FALSE)
   Portfolio2 <- Portfolio1[,6]
   holder <- monthlyReturn(Portfolio2)
    my_portfolio <- cbind( my_portfolio, holder )
   }
  #Applies ticker name to column
  names (my_portfolio) <- tickers

# Target 7%
eff_port <- portfolio.optim(my_portfolio, pm = 0.07, shorts = TRUE)
eff_port$pw

#Efficiency Frontier
#Mean Returns
mu <- colMeans(my_portfolio)
grid <- seq(0.005, 0.033, length.out = 60)

vector_pm <- rep(NA, length(grid))
vector_psd <- rep(NA, length(grid))
eff_weights <- matrix(NA, 60, 18)
#FOR LOOP
for (i in 1 : length(grid)) {
  eff.port <- portfolio.optim(my_portfolio, pm = grid[i], shorts =TRUE)
  vector_pm[i] <- eff.port$pm
  vector_psd[i] <- eff.port$ps
  eff_weights[i, ] <- eff.port$pw
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention, that you always get the same return. I think it is due to your first loop. You calculate the monthly return N-time for your portfolio2. Which is equal to Portfolio1[,6].

**EDIT 1**

So another thing would be again at the specification of the Portfolio2. Before you start your loop you save the Portfolio2 <- Portfolio1[,6] which takes always the same column of stock 'DPZ'. I think you wanted to update this specification with every iteration, as you also take always another ticker[i] but do not update the Portfolio2. Since you do not save the getSymbol.yahoo() nowhere. please try following loop for the first one:

```
for(i in 2:length(tickers)){
   ticker1 <- c('DPZ','SPY','AMD','AAPL','TSLA','MSFT','V', 'WMT', 'SQ','EA','ATVI','AMZN','ROKU', 
  'PYPL','KO','AXP','CCL','DFS')

# here is my change##############
   Portfolio1 <- getSymbols.yahoo(tickers[i], from="2016-01-01", to= "2018-12-31", auto.assign=FALSE)
#################

   Portfolio2 <- Portfolio1[,6]
   holder <- monthlyReturn(Portfolio2)
    my_portfolio <- cbind( my_portfolio, holder )
   }
```

Comment: The [,6] is in reference to pull the 6th column of the stock. I specifically am looking at the Adjusted values. I attempted your code and was met with an error

Comment: please try my edit1 mentioned in my answer. If not, could you provide the error message?